# Give marquee's effect to placeholder

Tags: html, css

I have a input tag, and the input has  a placeholder attribute. then I want to make the placeholder text scrolling automatically just like marquee.

it is possible to make it? If yes, how can I do it, by add marquee tag inside the placeholder attribute,  use CSS, or something else?
Please if it possible, prevent from using javascript, especially library, except no other way to do it...

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marquee feature is obsolete although it may work in some browsers. It's not good practice to use marquee. Try avoiding it

Concerning your question you can't use marquee inside placeholder whereas you can use transition in placeholder